# How to link different sets of information to one cell in excel

Tags: excel

So basically I have a project to make in school and I have a sheet of data. It has names of people and their daily use of electricity, gas and production for 90 days. I have linked each day to the usage on that day but it only links to the first person (I used HLOOKUP). I need to link those days to the users so when I change the user and the day it changes to the usage on that day. How do I do that? I'm stuck.

Comment: Please provide some test data and expected output, it will help us understand better you requirements.  Also include the HLOOKUP you tried, again to give us more insight into your problem

Comment: I don't currently have the document since it's stored on my computer in school, but I will try to get it as soon as possible :)